# csv, r - 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector

Tags: r, csv

I tried to use this R code:

```
fitBData <- function(filePath="PATH") {

   dataset <- read.table(filePath, header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NaN")
   clusterdata <- dataset[,3:7]
   # rownames(clusterdata) <- dataset$WallPrimAddr
   clusterdata_norm <- clusterdata


# clusterdata <- clusterdata[rowSums(is.na(clusterdata_norm))==0,]

# print( clusterdata_norm[rowSums(is.na(clusterdata_norm))>0,])
   wss <- (nrow(clusterdata_norm)-1)*sum(apply(clusterdata_norm,2,var))
   # print(sum(is.na(clusterdata_norm)))

   for (i in 2:30) {
        km <- kmeans(clusterdata_norm,centers=i)
        # print(km$totss)
        wss[i] <- sum(km$withinss)
    }
   plot(1:30, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
   fit <- kmeans(clusterdata_norm, 11)

   results <- data.frame(dataset, fit$cluster)
   colnames(results)[20] <- "ClusterNumber"

   write.table(results, "PATH", sep=",")
   write.table(fit$centers, "PATH", sep=",")

}
```

to run a k-mean clustering over data in csv file, in this form:

```
WalletNodeID,WallPrimAddr,pageRank,averageNumInputPerDay,averageNumOutputPerDay,averageInputVolumePerDay,averageOutputVolumePerDay
3,3GpGgT3sFxcBtt6JZRG3Kn7N4JfmsszXy6,47.25590464,5.205061695,0.035746272,0.581360333,0.120171064
4,3376X6m1YX3Jm4J4c2zq8w93VdSnUnZj31,0.088634463,-0.192355963,-0.040254904,0.020482286,-0.085882672
```

The first two column are only for identification of each entity.

After running the code, this error is thrown:

```
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [20] must be the same length as the vector [8]
```

I found it strange as the data file is an excerpt from another data file with 21 columns. And the code works on that another data files without any problem (with line `clusterdata <- dataset[,3:21]` for the line `clusterdata <- dataset[,3:7]` in the code shown).

Why is it so?

Comment: `results` has 8 columns, and you try to (re)name the non-existant 20th column.

Comment: Thank you. (Sorry I am a beginner.)

Comment: You're welcome. (And... every1 is.. in a way.. ;-) )